# Python: Want to download all apk files from website

Tags: python

I am working on an Android malware analysis project for that I have to create a benign android dataset(need approx 20000 .apk files).

so I want to download all .apk files from [website](https://www.9apps.com/) in python

```
import requests
import wget
import os

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, SoupStrainer

url = 'https://www.9apps.com/'

file_types = ['.apk']

for file_type in file_types:

    response = requests.get(url)

    for link in BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser', parse_only=SoupStrainer('a')):
        if link.has_attr('href'):
            if file_type in link['href']:
                full_path = url + link['href']
                wget.download(full_path)
```

but it is not working.

Comment: What is the error??

Comment: @sanketmokashi but it is downloading only two files and i want all .apk files available on wesite

Comment: Are you sure that the website itself does not limit your downloads as a sort of anti-ddos method?

Comment: I need to collect a dataset of benign apps as well. Did you manage to extract benign apps? Do you have the dataset that you would like to share?